# Proof that e Converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have to proof that e converges and have to use the below as direct comparison.

0 < $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}< \frac{1}{n*(n!)}$

but I get:

if (e= $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!})-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} < \frac{1}{n*(n!)} = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} 
\implies \sum_{n}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!} < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ ???

Comment: $e$ is a number. How does a number converge?

Comment: Why not simply use $k!\ge 2^k$ for $k>1$ and sum the geometric series?

Comment: I´m missing 2 brackets there, that e = the first sum is given, but still, where is my mistake?

Comment: @Dr.MV Or use the ratio test, which of course is also a comparison with a geometric series, in disguise.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, among a host of other ways forward.

Comment: @Bungo do i use the test for both and show that the second one is larger? because i have to use this inequation

Comment: What equation must you use??

Comment: @Dr.MV 0 < $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}< \frac{1}{n*(n!)}$

Comment: That is not an equation.

Comment: I wrote inequation, is it neither an inequation?

Comment: @Dr.MV sry, not a native, thought this is valid tho https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequation
Yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get
$$
\frac1{(n+1+k)!}\le\frac1{(n+1)!}\frac1{(n+1)^k}
$$
which tells you that the series remainder has a geometric series as majorant and thus is finite and converges.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1+k)!}\le\frac1{(n+1)!}·\frac1{1-\frac1{n+1}}
$$
Resolving the double fraction gives your result.

Comment: Well done.  Clear and concise. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I now got this, is this a valid proof?

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}< \frac{1}{n*(n!)}$
$\implies$ $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}< \frac{1}{n*(n!)}+ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$

using : $\frac{1}{n*(n!)} $ = $\frac{1}{(n+1)!} $

$\implies \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!} $
$\implies \implies \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}< \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!} $